# How to add a custom UITableViewCell to a xib file objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I want to load my custom xib for tableviewcell in view controller.I can't load my xib in tableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[CustomCell reuseIdentifier]];
    if (cell == nil) {
           [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
           cell = _customCell;
           _customCell = nil;
    }        

    cell.topLabel.text = @"I am on top";
    cell.bottomLabel.text = @"and I'm on the bottom";

    return cell;     
}
```

I cant't load my custom cell from xib into tableview.
 Please help me.

Comment: what the problem u faced

Comment: `-loadNibNamed:` does not even assign the returned array of objects from XIB anywhere. No wonder why nothing works.

Comment: @Tejas have you got any Error?

Comment: Tejas Chauhan see my detailed answer.My answer must be unique and works fine.That is the reason only I posted my answer for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this in Tableview cellforrowAtIndexPath methods,

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellData";

NSArray *arrData = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"cellTaskDetail" owner:nil options:nil];

cellTaskDetail *cell = [[cellTaskDetail alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell = [arrData objectAtIndex:0];

return cell;
```

Its work fine...do it

Answer (score 9):

There are two options:

**OPTION 1**

First you can **Register the Custom Cell in viewDidLoad**

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil];
[tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

Then in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** of TableView DataSource methods:

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
cell.lblName.text = @"Tejas";
```

---

**OPTION 2**

**If you are not registering the cell in viewDidLoad**, you have to do the following things in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** of TableView DataSource methods:

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
if(cell == nil)
   cell = nibs[0];
cell.lblName.text = @"Tejas";
return cell;
```

Answer (score 1):

Register the cell(XIB Cell) in the UITableView using the following method:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithName:nibName bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
```

Then you can dequeue the cell using the identifier you used for registering the cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];   
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)       
{       
    NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];   
    cell = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];    
}

cell.topLabel.text = @"I am on top";
cell.bottomLabel.text = @"and I'm on the bottom";

return cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `loadNibNamed` simple solution

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    YourCustomeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {     cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourCustomeCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    // do code with cell here

    return cell;
}
```